# Shouldn't we consider larger standard errors for effect measures or outcomes that are converted in meta-analysis?

Tags: variance, meta-analysis, data-imputation, weights

There are methods to convert effect measures in meta-analysis ([pdf](https://www.meta-analysis.com/downloads/Meta-analysis%20Converting%20among%20effect%20sizes.pdf)). There are also methods to convert outcomes; at least, I am aware of the conversion described in Furukawa et al. (2005) from continuous to binary outcomes.

In both cases, the values calculated from original data are different from the ones we are looking for, so we are just estimating the measures we need, by making assumptions (in the case of effect measures, the logistic distribution; as for outcomes, the normal distribution). Why can we put such estimates together with real sample values? Shouldn't we take into account that they are actually imputed, so include somehow an extra-variance component? I understand we can make sensitivity analyses by excluding them (or, in the case of binary outcomes, by looking at the best-case and the worst-case scenarios), but why don't we simply weight such studies less (or, equivalently, increase the standard error associated to them)?

Furukawa, T., Cipriani, A., Barbui, C., Brambilla, P., & Watanabe, N. (2005). Imputing response rates from means and standard deviations in meta-analyses. International clinical psychopharmacology, 20 1, 49-52.